# Elasticsearch DSL 'top_hits' Aggregation Not allowing 'From' Parameter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Elasticsearch aggregation 'top_hits' provides these three options:
[image]

When I try to write the query with the '**from**' parameter in elasticsearch_dsl, it gives an invalid syntax error. Does elasticsearch_dsl not allow the 'from' parameter or am I missing something?
Here is my elasticsearch_dsl query:

```
    s = Search(using=client, index=index).params(size=0)

    s.aggs.bucket('duplicateCount', 'terms', field=field, min_doc_count=2) \
        .bucket('duplicateDocuments', 'top_hits', sort=[{f"{sort_field}":"desc"}], from=2)
```

Here's the error msg:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the error you get?

Comment: I've updated the question with error msg.

Comment: which version of the Elasticsearch server and elasticsearch client python library are you using?

Comment: Elasticsearch dsl version is 7.0.0 and the elasticsearch cluster is 7.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `top_hits` is a metric aggregation (i.e. not a bucket one) you need to use the `metric()` function, not the `bucket()` one. Also since `from` is a reserved keyword in Python, you need to put it between single quotes.

```
s.aggs.bucket('duplicateCount', 'terms', field=field, min_doc_count=2) \
    .metric('duplicateDocuments', 'top_hits', sort=[{f"{sort_field}":"desc"}], **{'from': 2})
       ^
       |
  change this
```

Comment: It's giving the same error with metric. Also, 'top_hits' works with bucket aggregation, the issue is with the from parameter only.

Comment: I would upgrade your elasticsearch dsl lib to 7.10.2

Comment: You should still use `metric` for metric aggregations and not `bucket`

Comment: I upgraded it to 7.4.0 but didn't help.

Comment: since `from` is a reserved keyword in Python, you need to put it between single quotes. Try again

Comment: Yes, that worked. Just single quotes didn't work so I tried this
 **{'from': 2}
and it worked. Thanks. Could you please update your answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: Could glad we figured it out. updated!